# Better way to access distant cousin in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a script working to show hide the next() tbody element when another link is clicked, but it's uuuugly, and I'm sure I could do it more efficiently. Specifically I dont like using 4 parent() calls! Is there a better way to traverse things than that?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pooey long jQuery example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="thin">
        <tbody class="shown_rows">
            <tr>
                <td><span>td1</span></td>
                <td><span>td2</span></td>
                <td><span><a href="#" class="do-thing">Show</a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="hidden_rows">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7"><span>Temp txt</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="shown_rows">
            <tr>
                <td><span>td1</span></td>
                <td><span>td2</span></td>
                <td><span><a href="#" class="do-thing">Show</a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="hidden_rows">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7"><span>Temp txt</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
table td {border: 1px solid black;padding:2px;}
table .shown_rows * span {
    width:100px; display:block
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hidden_rows").hide();
$(".do-thing").click(function(e) {
     $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next("tbody").toggle("fast");
});
```

jSFiddleydeeee:
[This example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meredevelopment/pEwZh/)

Any thoughts?

(Note, I'm using spans on purpose, and this is a simplified example for the question only so it looks horrid in FF and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to go up the tree to the nearest element that matches a selector, then.

```
$(this).closest('tbody').next('tbody').toggle('fast');
```

Note that `next('tbody')` could almost certainly be shortened to `next()`, since you don't have `thead` or `tfoot` elements.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect, and thanks for explaining that the next() could be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` jQuery method which get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
$(this).closest('tbody').next().toggle('fast');
```